# .splice method not removing correct item in array in d3

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

I am working with a scatterplot in d3 and dots on the graph represent a paper. Dots are set to a type. The dots I want to talk about are all of type  *In_library* . removeFromlibrary is a function which is defined in an option in a drop down menu. In this function I make a connection to the data base to update a boolean false value in the **column** Library.

But I also want to remove this item from my data array. And then I want to call a function called refreshGraph() which clears the graph and redraws dots using the updated array. The way I am trying to remove this item from the array (thus removing it from display once the refreshGraph function is called) is by doing the following:

```
title: 'Remove from Library',
action: function removeFromLibrary (elem, d, i) {

    d3.json("connection9.php?paperID="+d.ID, function(error, dataJson) {

        if (d.type === "In_library") {
            allData.splice(d, 1);
        }

        refreshGraph();

        })          
    }
```

So, if the dot I select is of type  *In_library* (which it is) I want to remove THAT ITEM from the array. 
This doesnt work and when I select a dot and select the remove from library option in the menu it will remove a different paper that has the type "In_library". A possible cause of this is that the index given to the .splice method is wrong..?

I am new to d3 so any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice. You are using `splice` wrong.

Comment: @putvande any advice on how I could correctly use it and remove the right object from the array?? thanks

Comment: You need the index of your element inside the array. Do you know the index of `d` inside the `allData` array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the comments, your use of splice is wrong (reference: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)) - rather than inputting the item itself, you need to use the item's index in the Array.

Making use of `Array.prototype.indexOf` should do the trick:

```
if (d.type === "In_library") {
  var index_d = allData.indexOf(d);
  if (index_d != -1) allData.splice(index_d, 1);
}
```